# How do I get browser's window height from firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make add-on's panel size responsive depending on the browser's window height. 
How do I get browser's window height from firefox add-on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.innerHeight
```

But make sure `window` is not the content window, but the browser, XUL, window.

Comment: This is the problem. It returns null. How do i bind it to the browser?

Comment: Noitidart, Any ideas?

Comment: @stkvtflw Im not sure how you are getting the window. I usually deal with windows from a window listener or from window enumerator: `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').innerHeight`

Answer (score -1):

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var window = wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
console.log(window.gBrowser.clientWidth, window.gBrowser.clientHeight);
```